# Using SQL/Presto/Athena, Merge records by ID maintaining the timestamp column order as the most recent

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

is it possible to do a merge by timestamp on records with same id, according to the most recent timestamp?

For example, imagine a table with the following records for the user_id = 1.

| user_id | name | address | city | state | op_id | benefit | phone | insert_date_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  | 0 |  |  | 2021-06-22 15:06:29.083534 |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 99999999 | 2021-06-22 15:06:29.153258 |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  | N |  | 2021-06-22 15:03:29.153258 |
| 1 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | 2021-06-22 15:01:29.153258 |
| 1 |  | 999 St | PHOENIX | AZ |  |  |  | 2021-06-22 14:06:29.153258 |
| 1 | Jonh Doe | Doe |  |  |  |  |  | 2021-06-21 15:06:29.153258 |

You can see that overtime there was multiple new entries inserted, and if I merge all the records from older to the newest the current record would be:

result

| user_id | name | address | city | state | op_id | benefit | phone | insert_date_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jonh Doe | 999 St | PHOENIX | AZ | 0 | N | 99999999 | 2021-06-22 15:06:29.083534 |

How can I achieve this with SQL? and is it possible to produce the same with PRESTO/Athena query?

PS: I understand that this can be done using Pyspark, pandas etc... my usecase is for Athena

Thank you!!

Solution

```
select distinct user_id,
       first_value(name) ignore nulls over (partition by user_idorder by insert_date desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as name,
       first_value(address) ignore nulls over (partition by user_id order by insert_date desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as address,
       . . .
from t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `first_value()`:

```
select distinct user_id,
       first_value(name) over (partition by user_id, name is not null desc order by insert_date desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as name,
       first_value(address) over (partition by user_id, address is not null desc order by insert_date desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as address,
       . . .
from t;
```

Or if you prefer with `ignore nulls`:

```
select distinct user_id,
       first_value(name) ignore nulls over (partition by user_idorder by insert_date desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as name,
       first_value(address) ignore nulls over (partition by user_id order by insert_date desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as address,
       . . .
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you it almost solve it, but it always return 2 rows, using the ignore nulls, the first one returns 3 rows..., do you have any idea why Im getting 2 rows from the second one? first how will ssome nulls, and second with the values. correct

Comment: @tubadc . . . In my mind, I was hoping to avoid the need for a window frame specification.  But I think that is necessary.

Comment: Got it! added rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following